# Drill mounting holes

Tags: pi-3, retropie

I've bought a kit with a shield that seems to have bigger screws than the one supported by the Raspberry Pi 3 (they are 3MA, so I guess 3mm vs [2.75mm](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/hardware/raspberrypi/mechanical/Raspberry-Pi-3B-V1.2-Mechanical.pdf)).

Do you think it's too risky to use a Dremel to make them slightly bigger?

[image: Mounting holes]

Comment: I would just by appropriately sized screws (M2.5) and standoffs. And complain to whoever manufactured the shield, because the mounting hole size is hardly a secret...

Comment: Are you willing to ruin a $35 Pi over a $2 worth of new hardware?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's fine. I've done it on loads. There is nothing it fouls. Don't go too large with the bolt head. I opened mine to 3.8mm.
[Old post about opening up the holes](https://plus.google.com/+AndyAnderson/posts/Hd39b3zAoBT)

Comment: Yeah, that's the wrong URL. Should be fixed now. Sorry about that.

Comment: Thats alright! :) Though should of added usually it is worth including most of the relevant contents of the link here in case it breaks in future

Answer (score 1):

It shouldn’t be, because it’s not interfering with the board directly. Make sure you use a precise bit however!

Comment: How do you know its is not interfering with the board directly? Even assuming there is no circuit traces near the holes, going at them with a drill is still risky. You could slip and damage part of the board or possibly crack the board in the process.

Comment: Place tape over the hole and make sure you have a steady hand is all I can offer, the correct method is obviously get the right screws, but if that’s all OP has access to then drilling is a way to go

Comment: @DarthVader I know because I did some research, asked a few questions and then took a drill to my Raspberry Pi and the result was - it continues to work. Pretty conclusive I think. I find your lack of faith disturbing...